Trouble with MATLAB reading in excel cells with numeric and alphabetic values of differing lengths
I am working with MATLAB, and I am using data from an excel file. For my stations names I am having trouble reading in the data. EX:  row in excel example   I need it to accept when some have A at the end, but not have an error if not.
    for i = 1:length(data(1:i))
        % Process stations
        station_info = textscan(char(stations{i}), '%s%4.2f', 'Delimiter', '-');
        %Loc{i} = station_info{1}{1};
        %statnum(i) = station_info{2};
        stationOpts = detectImportOptions(t, 'Sheet', 'gdata', 'DataRange', 'A1:BJ7');
        readstations = readtable(t, stationOpts);
    
        % Process samples
        %Samp{i} = char(samples{i});
    
    % Process intervals
    interval_info = textscan(char(intervals{i}), '%4.2f %4.2f','delimiter','-');
   

    [Samp(i)]=strread(char(samples(i)),'%s%4.2f','-');
        [samptop(i) sampbot(i)]=strread(char(intervals(i)),'%4.2f %4.2f','delimiter','-');
    end

Warning: Colon operands must be real scalars.

In detectImportOptions (line 423)

ALSO TRIED:
for i=1:length(data(1,:))
    [Loc(i) statnum(i)]=strread(char(stations(i)), '%s %4.2f','delimiter','-' ); % find the core numbers for each sample
    [Samp(i)]=strread(char(samples(i)),'%s');
    [samptop(i) sampbot(i)]=strread(char(intervals(i)),'%4.2f %4.2f','delimiter','-');
end

Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements.
here is my code I am having an error with. let me know if you have any suggestions Thanks!


I think the below code will meet your requirements:

for i = 1:length(data(1,:))
    if endsWith(str(stations(i)), "A") == True
        
        [insert code you want to run when string ends with "A"]
    else
        "error, no A at the end"
        break
    end
end


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
